# Externalizing DEFAULT configuration properties

Tags: java, properties, groovy, configuration-files, gradle

A lot of projects are using configuration files and
I found a lot of posts how to read this configuration files, how to externalize them, but I couldn't find anything about how to generate a sample configuration file.

For example, if you have a **company.config** file full with all kind of configuration properties, I would like that a **company.sample.config** file is automatically generated from my source code every time I build the project. This sample file should contain all the configuration properties used by the project, together with default values and comments.

I use Java and Gradle, so I was thinking about a Gradle plugin.

Is there something like this out there? How are other people solving this problem?

---

> Later Edit: Some example:

---

```
public class CompanyConfig {
private static final String PROPERTY1_DEFAULT = "Company.property1_default";
private static final String PROPERTY2_DEFAULT = "Company.property2_default";

/**
 * description 1
 */
private static final String PROPERTY1 = "Company.property1";
/**
 * description 2
 */
private static final String PROPERTY2 = "Company.property2";

private Config config;

public CompanyConfig(Config config) {
    this.config = config;
}

public String getProperty1() {
    return config.getProperty(PROPERTY1, PROPERTY1_DEFAULT);
}

public String getProperty2() {
    return config.getProperty(PROPERTY2, PROPERTY2_DEFAULT);
}
}
```

BAsed on the above code, the sample.conf file should look like this:

```
**description 1
*Company.property1=Company.property1_default

**description 2
*Company.property2=Company.property2_default
```

In this way, I can give the sample.conf file to someone who wants to configure the project. This person has no idea about the configuration properties in my project, so he/she needs a list of properties and a default value for each property. And because new peoperties are introduced and some others are removed, the sample file has to be generated with every build.

Hope this clarifies what I'm asking here.

Comment: the standard java.util.Properties provides a way to write a Properties instance to an OutputStream with a comment (not a comment for each property mind you).

Comment: I want something automatically: parse my code and extract the names of the properties and the defaults. This has to be a plugin of some kind.

Comment: How would you recognize all the configuration properties in your code?

Comment: Well, this is the question. I was thinking about Annotations or some convention: The Config classes should have a specific pattern (*ConfigImpl) and the fields should have also a specfic pattern (*_Property)...or somehting like this. Could be that there are some other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of ant build script. take help of below code.

```
<project>
<target name="default">



<propertyfile file="company.sample.config" comment="sample properties here.">

<entry key="program.AUTHOR" default="RAIS" />
<entry key="program.COMPANY" default="IGT" />
<entry key="program.COPYRIGHT" default="now" type="date" pattern="yyyy" />
<entry key="program.DESCRIPTION" default="" />
<entry key="program.VERSION" default="1.0.0" />
<entry key="program.BUILDNUM" value="1" />
<entry key="program.BUILDDATE" type="date" value="now" pattern="yyyyMMDDHHmmss" />
</propertyfile>

</target>
</project>
```

Comment: Ok. I will go a bit more in detail. Probably I was to general?

Comment: Am i answered your question or you are looking for otherthing.

Comment: I edited my question to better reflect what I need. Your answer doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Are you are using any tool like ant or maven to build your application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a plugin that would do this but if you have a decent configuration system then it shouldn't be hard to do.  For example, I use a configuration system which is based on JSON: the configuration file is a simple JSON document which maps directly in to configuration object.  To generate a sample configuration with default values you would just instantiate the base object and ask JSON to write it out which is a five-line program and could easily be added to a build script.

Comment: what about the comments for each field? The configuration which I used now is apache.commons.configuration.

Comment: Don't know about Apache, I'd stick to a JSON-based solution and write a custom writer to pull the comments from each field as well.  A bit more effort, but not too much.

Comment: The problem with the JSON approach is that you don't have a fall-back strategy. The Apache solution gives you a lot of power in configuring the project: different configuration files with different priorities based on the lifecycle, possibility to get the system environments in the priority list etc

Comment: Yep true.  Works fine in my environment, and personally I think that having configuration in multiple places is a Bad Thing, but if you need or rely on it then this won't help.  Sorry!